# How to correctly validate in jquery for a empty text input

Tags: jquery, html

This is my jQuery code to validate a html table:

```
function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("[class*='q']").each(function (i) {
        var questions = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text());
        var txtinput = $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val();
        _qid = questions;
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


        if (txtinput == '' || txtinput == null) {
            alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
        } else if (marks < '0') {

            alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) + " Marks";
        } else if (marks > '0') {

            alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining";
        }

        if (alertValidation != "") {
            return false; //Stop the each loop 
        }

    });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now what I find strange is that if the validation for when the number of marks remaining is higher than 0 and the validation for when the number of marks remainig is lower than 0 works perfectly when the alert is outputted as it displays this below:

**Higher than 0:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 1
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Have 7 Marks Remaining
```

**Less than 0:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 1
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Need To Remove 3 Marks
```

But when I try to validate to see if a text input under the "Marks per Answer" section is empty, then it displays this message below:

```
You have errors on Question Number: NaN

• You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
```

Why can't it display the question number for this validation?

Also another slight problem I have is that even if I have entered in a value in all the text inputs under "Marks per Answer", it still displays the above validation message alert when it shouldn't do. Why does it do this as well?

Below is an example html table:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionId?>_qnum" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">1 <input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q1_ans" class="q1_ans" value="5"></td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" class="individualtext" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" />
</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length to check whether the attribute have empty text instead of != ""

```
alertValidation.length > 0
```

and could you please check the below code

```
parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
```

if this $("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text() is undefined then parseInt will return the NaN only

Thanks

Comment: Hi, but what I don't get is that how can it be NaN for this validation but for the other validations it displays the question number? I have tested it on a bigger table with more records and it works perfect for the higher than or less than 0 validations but it displays NaN for question number when validation empty text inputs. Is the way I am seelcting and checking for empty text inputs under "Marks per Asnwer" column correct?

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
alert($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());

or debug using google chrome or firebug,

I believe the 
each() catch the class that are not exist in your web, or it contains character, space that can't be parse to Int, which caused NaN in your script, try to check it out