# It still states I have an empty text input even though there are no empty text inputs left

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/74

The problem I am having is that it is not displaying the question number in the alert but instead displays NaN. Also even though all the text inputs have been filled in, it still displays an alert stating have I have an empty text input.

What am I doing incorrectly in my fiddle?

Jquery validation() function is here:

```
function validation() {

        var alertValidation = "";
        var _qid = "";
        var _msg = "";

        $("[class*='q']").each(function(i) {  
        var questions = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text()); 
        var txtinput = $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(); 
        _qid = questions;
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


    if (txtinput == '' || txtinput == null) {
        alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
    }    

                if (alertValidation != "") {
                    return false; //Stop the each loop 
                }

            });


        if (alertValidation != "") {
            alert(_msg + alertValidation);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It's `questions` itself that is NaN. `$("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]")` is targeting nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value here is $("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]") empty, the web can't find the class as you want, class="q0_qnum" for  when your "i" is 0

Comment: you had already created the same thread at here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715987/how-to-correctly-validate-in-jquery-for-a-empty-text-input/13718323#13718323

Comment: Can you update the fiddle and show me what that line of code should be?

Comment: That is not my thread, Im guessing somebody else has the same problem in this assignment.

Comment: ooo, sorry for that, thought is the same user with different id, aha

Comment: I realise the problem isn't the question number or what you have referred to. The problem is checking if its blank if statement. i don't know if its because of keypress it doesn't retrieve a blank text input or I have coded it incorrectly to check for blank input but if you change the if statement to see if txtinput == 5, then it displays the question number in the alert and the alert works fine. Its only when it tries to check for blank input is where I get the problem.

Comment: Figured it out, I had to remove txtinput == null, and remove multiple ids and the alert displays the question number. But there is a problem. In the fiddle as you can see, question 1 has 2 text inputs. But if I fill in one text input in question 1, when I submit, it should display an alert stating that there is an empty text input in question 1 as we have left the other one empty, but it doesn't display an alert for this. It skips it and instead starts going through the other validation . What is up with that? Fiddle updated